# How to do collapse and expand view in mac application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, expand, nsviewcontroller

I am new to mac application development, here i want to do expand and collapse view in my custom view(NSView)

here the sample image

[image]

How can i achieve these kind of collapse and expand cell in NSViewController not in NSWindow...

Is it possible using NSTableView?

I know its a simple question but i facing problem.

Please suggest me some sample code or links..

Thanks

Comment: How far have you got? What *specifically* is the problem you're facing? The Xcode object library provides the Disclosure Triangle Button, so that's the hard part out of the way. Once you've got one of these on a view, all you need is a method that detects when this button is pushed, and you can then take responsibility for showing and hiding the relevant view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collapsing / expanding can be implemented by adjusting auto layout constraints in the action method of the disclosure triangle button.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *moreInfoBoxHeight;

[[self.moreInfoBoxHeight animator] setConstant:75];
```

Apple has sample code using NSStackView at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

The view at the picture given is NSOutlineView. It is the NSTableView subclass.

Look at the [Apple reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/index.html) and [Outline programming topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/OutlineView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000023i).